# What are allowed and not allowed to do in a linux Device Driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a general question about linux device driver. More often I get confused which actions are allowed or not allowed to perform in a linux device driver?

Is there any rules or kind of lookup list to follow?

for instance with the following examples, which are not allowable?

```
msleep(1000);
al = kmallock(sizeof(val));
printk(KERN_ALERT "faild to print\n";
ret = adc_get_val()*0.001;
```

Comment: Read a book, start programming drivers yourself, etc. Here you have one non-compileable line, and last one is not for kernel, since it does not use floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux device driver programming it depends in which context you are. There are two contexts that need to be distinguished:

- process context
- IRQ context.

Sleeping can only be done while in process context or you schedule the work for later execution (there are several mechanism available to do that). This is a complex topic that cannot be described in a paragraph.

Allocating memory can sleep, it depends with which parameters/flags kmalloc is invoked.

print can always be called (once the kernel has been invoked), otherwise use early_printk.

I don't know what the function add_get_val does. It is not part of the linux kernel. And as has already been commented, float values cannot be easily used in the kernel.